# Google-Maps requests - Can Google see my Domain?

Tags: html, google-maps, request, server

For example: I have a `<img>` on my Website to the Google-Maps-API (static Maps). Is it possible for Google to see the HTTP_HOST/Domain (mydomain.com) or only the Client-IP by each request by the Client?

Answer (score 0):

In http protocol normally in GET method (like i presume is used for obtain the statics maps)  the Header of the request  contain in the `refer`  attribute the URL of the referring page  see [request_field](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_header_fields#Request_fields)